# CodeIgniter 404 Page Not Found htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I got 404 Page Not Found when I tried to access my file without the index.php. 
this is my .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /HR/
# If your project is in server root then should be: RewriteBase/
# If project is in folder then it should be: RewriteBase /folder_name/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^.(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you using local host if so what one xampp, wamp etc what version of codeigniter

Comment: im using xampp. i already set up the things needed to. i have watched a lot of tutorial and it still isnt working. i thought maybe there's something wrong with the code of my htaccess.

Comment: I have added my answer please give it ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using this one

Place this in main directory out side of application folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also make sure if your using codeigniter 3 that the **first letter** of class and file name must be uppercase only.

Comment: still not working. :( do you think i have other errors ? what are my other possible errors ?

Comment: maybe the link? my link is localhost/foldername/index.php/filename/class, then i just removed the index.php..

Comment: oh, my bad, my ht access is not working because i used uppercase on the folder path. but anyway, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: .htaccess vary depending on server. In some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: still not working. :( do you think i have other errors ? what are the other possible errors ?

Comment: maybe the link? my link is localhost/foldername/index.php/filename/class, then i just removed the index.php..

Comment: oh, my bad, my ht access is not working because i used uppercase on the folder path. but anyway, thanks! :)